# Trying to create a program that sums up two items in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Hello Stack Overflow Community,
I'm trying to write a program that will take the numbers inputted (by the user) in an array and sum up two numbers in opposite order. For example, the array has 10 entries, so it's the 1st + 10th, then the 2nd + 9th, each putting the sum on a new line. I have a current program for starts but I can't get the method or array needed. I tried to create a 2nd array that has the initial input in reverse order so that I can sum the entries but when I try to print the list I get an error. Here is the code:

I am a very beginner coder so any help with what the code would look like would be highly appreciated!

```
import java.text.*; // general package for formatting
import java.util.Scanner; // for scanner
import javax.swing.*;

public class ArraySummation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;
        int number, j = 0;
        int[] arr, arr2;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
        number = keyboard.nextInt();

        arr = new int[number];
        for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
            System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            arr[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        arr2 = new int[arr.length];
        for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            arr2[j++] = arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println(arr);
        System.out.println(arr2);
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Sum up two numbers'? What two numbers? You seem to just be copying items from the first array into the second array in reverse order. There are no numbers (besides 0) in the second array after you initialize it.

Comment: What error are you currently getting?

Comment: The 2nd array is copying the 1st array in reverse order. My objective is to set up a loop that will sum arr + arr2 for 1/2 the length. Meaning that the loop will take the first 5 numbers in arr and sum with the corresponding arr2 number. I don't know how to set up the method/loop for summing.

Comment: This is my current error:

Comment: this code does not cause an error, but it prints the arrays as object.toString() which results in something similar to [I@38540408
so you are on the right track, now make the loop to sum items, though you may be able to make 1 smart loop with 1 array to sum the items, arr[i-1] + arr[arr.length-i] (i=1;i<=arr.length/2;i++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ArraySummation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;
        int number, j = 0;
        int[] arr, arr2;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to enter? ");
        number = keyboard.nextInt();

        arr = new int[number];
        for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
            System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            arr[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        arr2 = new int[arr.length];
        for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            arr2[j++] = arr[i];
        }
        //I believe you have reversed arr into arr2 correctly
        //this should print them out the way you wanted
        for(int i=0;i<(arr.length/2);i++){
            System.out.println("Adding " + arr[i] + " and " + arr2[i] + ": ");
            System.out.println(arr[i] + arr2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: assume i =0, this will sum arr[0] + arr2[0] OP does not want this.

Comment: Would this not add the first item and last item since arr2 is arr reversed? This should work as desired except for odd length arrays, OP has not specified that behavior

Comment: oh, yes i missed that :) sorry

Answer (score 1):

here is another answer just using 1 array and 1 loop to sum
no need for a 2nd (reversed) array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;
        int number, j = 0;
        int[] arr, arr2;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
        number = keyboard.nextInt();

        arr = new int[number];
        for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
            System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            arr[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        int half = arr.length/2;
        //System.out.println("half " + half);
        for(int r=1; r<=half;r++){
            System.out.println(arr[r-1] + arr[arr.length-r]);
        }//for loop

        //if array lenth is odd, then middle item will not have an item from the other half, so sum it with itself
        if(arr.length%2!=0){
            System.out.println(arr[half] + arr[half]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: yup, but still has some tricky part in calculating indexes, yours is closer to what OP was doing